# Which debugger works with a "16 bits C to assembly" hybrid program?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, hybrid

(It is not a mere recommendation question; I couldn't find any debugger myself. So I guess I am not breaking the rules?)

The program's compiled with Turbo Assembler, Turbo Linker and BorlandC compilers. It is in Intel x86 architecture. (I am required to use those outdated programs; not my choice.)

Is there a simple debugger that would go well with it? I need to track the contents of registers, variables and flags during the program's execution.

Comment: Have you tried BCC built in debugger?

Comment: Turbo Debugger = http://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=280

Comment: All of those are Borland languages, and the Turbo Debugger that came with the Borland C compiler and IDE will debug them. With that being said, the fact you couldn't find a debugger yourself first does not make this question on-topic. It's still a request for us to find or recommend a tool, which is expressly indicated in the [help/on-topic] as being off-topic here.

Comment: @mtijanic Yes... so I guess I'll have to figure out how to debug a hybrid then. So far I succeeded only in analyzing single files (.asm OR .cpp) seperately, and thought a hybrid needed something else.

Comment: I've only done it with inline assembly in .cpp files, so no idea if that is possible. Perhaps you could wrap the assembly into cpp temporarily?